# I have ant installed in my MAC OS now i want to install Maven.Do i need to unistall ant first?

Tags: maven, ant

I have ant configured in my system now i need to configure Maven please help.
http://crunchify.com/how-to-install-maven-on-mac-os-x-manually-fix-unsupportedclassversionerror-orgapachemavenclimavencli/

I tried the steps of above but while editing bash.profile it shows
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/varunjoshi/ant/bin
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
"~/.bash_profile" 1L, 46C

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Maven into your **~/.bash_profile**, example:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/varunjoshi/ant/bin
export M2_HOME=/Users/varunjoshi/apache-maven-3.3.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Unable to open bash_profile.It says permission denied,I tried ~/bash.profile

Answer (score 0):

$nano .bash_profile

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

export M2_HOME=/Users/varunjoshi/apache-maven-3.3.3

export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin

$source .bash_profile

$mvn --version

Comment: JAVA_HOME was not setup properly. Added it to the bash_profile and then exported maven-3.3.3